# Replace all except multiple matches to keep

Tags: string, regex-negation

I have a string like:

```
"This is some text.|Some more text.|Some other text.|Some different text."
```

What I want to achieve is to select all text which is not matched by these conditions:

1. From the beginning of the line select the first n characters.
2. After each | select the first n characters.

If I set n=10 I should get this selection:

```
"me text.|text.| text.|rent text."
```

Final target is to replace the selected text with nothing,
so that the left over is:

```
"This is so, Some more , Some other, Some diffe"
```

I already came so far to select the text I want to keep, but unfortunately I need to replace the not needed text.

I hope this is doable.

This is the current state of regex I have:

```
^(.{20})|(\|)(.{20})
```

It gives me the text itself (including the | )
and I haven´t managed to adopt what I found so far on my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might use a capture group and a negated character class excluding matching a pipe.

```
([^\n|]{10})[^\n|]*(?:\||$)
```

The pattern matches:

- `(` Capture **group 1**

  - `[^\n|]{10}` Repeat 10 times matching a char other than a newline or `|`
- `)` Close group 1
- `[^\n|]*` Match optional chars other than a newline or `|`
- `(?:\||$)` Either match `|` or the end of the string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/4HywU9/1)

In the replacement use group 1, but note that if you are doing a single replacement there will be a trailing comma and a space that you would have after process and remove.

`$1,`

Output

```
This is so, Some more , Some other, Some diffe,
```

---

Another idea is to split on `|`, then loop the splitted results taking the first 10 characters and join back the results with `,`